# Does IntelliJ Idea 11 Community Edition has "go to resource" facility and how to access it if yes?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea Android tutorial suggests using "go to resource" facility appearing as a triangle in the left gutter area, but It doesn't seem to appear in my case (I am using IntelliJ Idea 11 Community Edition). Of course I can live without it, but it would be nice to use the feature if it is available. Is it? If it is, then how do I find it?

Comment: Check that appropriate facets are configured in project's settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle has been removed from the gutter to save space, navigation is performed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> while the caret is on the resource usage in the java file.